# Update String List Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to make a program in ASP.net where a user selects products from page 1 (default.aspx), clicks a button to put into shopping cart, and it appears in the second page of product list.

```
List<string> skuList = new List<string>();
if (validation)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                skuList.Add(row.Cells[2].Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
else { Response.Write("<script>alert('At least one product need to be selected!');</script>"); }
Session["sku"] = skuList;
```

The problem I am having is I can not update Session["sku"].

### Goal I want to reach:

on Page 1, user chooses product Number 1,2,3, then the session variable get updated to 1,2,3
on Page 2, user continue to choose product Number 8, then the session variable get updated to 1,2,3,8

I tried to do something like

```
 Session["sku"] = Session["sku"] + skulistt;
```

Of course it didn't work.

Comment: What (compiler/runtime) error did you get?

Comment: `List<string> skuList = (List<string>)Session["sku"];` Then `skuList.Add("New item");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have a misconception about session. The objects stored in session can be strongly-typed, but the typed returned is always object.  It would look something like the following (taking session out of the equation):

```
object myvar = new List<string>();

myvar.Add("mystring"); // will not compile because myvar is defined as object.
```

To use `myvar` as a list is needs to be cast to the correct type:

```
var myvar1 = (List<string>)myvar; 
// or 
var myvar2 = myvar as List<string>; 

myvar1.Add("mystring");
myvar2.Add("mystring");
```

The difference between `myvar` and `myvar1` is that `myvar` can hold a reference to any `object` type, so I could do:

```
object myvar = new List<string>();
myvar = new WebClient();
```

but I can't do that with `myvar` because it's been defined as `List<string>` which `WebClient` does not derive from.

So to add a string to the session variable, it needs to be cast as the correct type:

```
var mylist = (List<string>)Session["sku"];
list.Add("mystring");
```

However it looks like you just want to replace the value:

```
session["sku"] = skulistt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get List out of Session, add new element in List and then reassign to Session like this:

```
List<string> list= List<string>();

if(Session["sku"] != null)
     list = (List<string>)Session["sku"];

list.Add("item");

Session["sku"] = list;
```

**UPDATED:**

In your case do like this:

```
Session["sku"] = skulistt;
```

Change you code like:

```
List<string> list= List<string>();

if(Session["sku"] != null)
     list = (List<string>)Session["sku"];

if (validation)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                skuList.Add(row.Cells[2].Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
else { Response.Write("<script>alert('At least one product need to be selected!');</script>"); }
Session["sku"] = skuList;
```

Comment: I got the following error on the line of List.add(skuList)-->Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: so skulisst is itself list then do this: ``Session["sku"] = skulistt;``

Comment: this is wrong: ``Session["sku"] =Session["sku"] + skulistt;``

Comment: Session object is different, you cannot concatenate like you do in string case

Comment: I don't think [code] Session["sku"] = skuList is right; On page 1, skuList is 1,2,3 then on the second page skuList is 8. The session variable would end up with 8, overwritten by skuList.

Comment: you did'nt read my post i think you have to get previous list from session and then add new item in it and then assign to session again

Comment: before if instead of ``List<string> skuList = new List<string>();`` new list making get List from Session that is in Session: ``List<string> skuList = (List<string>)Session["sku"];`` and it will work fine

Comment: I did what you mentioned to replace the line. Now after I choose products, I am getting {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} error on the line of `code'(list.Add(row.Cells[2].Text))

Comment: you need to do this change on second page

Comment: also before getting from Session you have to check for null means if its first time you are creating and have not added in session in that case Session["sku"] object will be null